# Appending letters based on number of transaction in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Need a SQL query to append the letters to integer column
My sample data would be like

```
+--------+----------+--------+
| Number | Date     | amount |
+--------+----------+--------+
| 135    | 20160901 | $10    |
| 135    | 20160912 | $20    |
| 135    | 20160915 | $30    |
+--------+----------+--------+
```

Would need an output like below, results should be based on Date

```
+--------+--------+
| Number | amount |
+--------+--------+
| 135X   | $10    |
| 135XX  | $20    |
| 135XXX | $30    |
+--------+--------+
```

X is appended once, in first record because the record was first transaction in a month, XX in second as it was second transaction and so on, need to append the 'N' no of X's based on number of times that transaction has happened in a month.

Kindly suggest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select (cast(number as varchar(255)) +
        replicate('X', row_number() over (partition by number, year(date), month(date) order by date)
                 )
       ) as number,
       amount
from t;
```

You can use similar logic for updating the `Number` column, assuming it is a string column that is awkwardly named.

Comment: Thanks that did work, needed little changes and did it as per my need.